# R - subset data frame keeping only the rows that agree with multiple conditions over ALL columns

Tags: r, csv, filter, subset, grepl

Quick summary of what I want is this:

I have thousands of .csv files in the same folder that contain phrases such as *discount rate* or *discounted cash flow* mainly in the first column, but also randomly in the first 10 columns.

Using some function (maybe `grepl()`, `subset()`, or `filter()`), I would like to extract the row(s) containing these phrases and have them put into a new data frame along with the name of the file they each came from.

---

The issue I am having is that every function I have been experimenting with only allows for looking through one or 2 columns at a time. Here is the code i have been working with:

```
#Reading in a single .csv file for now:
MyData <- read.csv("c:/____________/.csv", header = TRUE, sep=",")

#Assigning numbers to each column since each file I will be plugging in has different column headings:
colnames(MyData) <- c(1:ncol(MyData))

#Using subset to check the 1st column and 5th column for discount rate 
#(only because I knew these 2 columns contained the phrase "discount rate" ahead of time.)
my.data.frame <- subset(MyData, MyData$`1`=="discount rate" | MyData$`5`=="discount rate")
```

---

So just to reiterate, I want to know if there is a way to search many phrases such as *discount rate*, *discounted rates*, and *discounted cash flow* over every column in some data.frame.  Thank you for any help you can provide.

Also, the code I provided does return rows where the columns specified included 
*discount rate*, but not rows that contained other words such as *the discount rate was 5.0%*. If a solution to this problem is known then I would be more than grateful.

[image: picture of the code I have been working with]

[image: Results from my code in a data frame]

Comment: Look into the `grep` function.

Comment: With grep, it seems complicated because you must specify a single column name to search through but all of the files I am looking through do not have a consistent name or amount of columns

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work? You can use regular expressions (regex) modify 
'discount' according to what you need.

```
#Sample dataframe with 'discount rate', 'discounted rates', or 'discounted cash flow' randomly placed
df <- data.frame(a=c('discount rate', 'nothing', 'discounted cash flow', 'nothing', 'nothing'), b=1:5,
  c=6:10, d=c('nothing', 'discounted rates', 'nothing', 'nothing', 'nothing'), stringsAsFactors = F)
df
                     a b  c                d
1        discount rate 1  6          nothing
2              nothing 2  7 discounted rates
3 discounted cash flow 3  8          nothing
4              nothing 4  9          nothing
5              nothing 5 10          nothing

#Get rows where the word 'discount' occurs in any row
discountRows <- unique(unlist(apply(df, 2, function(x) grep('discount', x))))

#Subset df with only rows where the word 'discount' occurs
df[discountRows,]
                     a b c                d
1        discount rate 1 6          nothing
3 discounted cash flow 3 8          nothing
2              nothing 2 7 discounted rates

#Assign subsetted df to new dataframe with original name in it
assign(paste0(deparse(substitute(df)), '_discountRows'), df[discountRows,])
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `grepl` (returning `TRUE/FALSE` on regex matches) placed inside an `apply`. And have all wrapped in a larger `lapply` to build a list of dataframes through your many csv files with subsetted rows and then row bind altogether at end:

```
setwd("C:/path/to/my/folder")
myfiles <- list.files(path="C:/path/to/my/folder")

dfList <- lapply(myfiles, function(file){
    df <- read.csv(file, header = TRUE)
    colnames(df) <- c(1:ncol(df))

    # ADD COLUMN FOR FILENAME
    df$filename <- file

    # RETURNS 1 IF ANY COLUMN HAS MATCH
    df$discountfound <- apply(df, 1, function(col) 
                              max(grepl("discount rate|discounted cash flow", col)))

    # SUBSET AND REMOVE discountfound COLUMN
    df <- transform(subset(df, df$discountfound == TRUE), discountfound=NULL)
})

# ASSUMES ALL DATAFRAMES HAVE EQUAL NUMBER OF COLUMNS
finaldf <- do.call(rbind, dfList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. I hope this is what you want.

```
mydata = data.frame(a = c(1:3,"discount rate","discounted rates",2:5),
                    b = c("discount rate","discounted rates",2:8))

row = c()
for (i in 1:nrow(mydata)){
  good_row = grep(paste("discount rate","discounted rates",sep="|"),unlist(mydata[i,]))
  if (length(good_row) != 0){
    row = c(row,i)
  }
}

mydata = mydata[row,]
```